# What functions can be used as 'key=func' arguments in the min() and max() functions?

Tags: python, max, min

For example:

```
names = ['Rodrigo', 'Matthew', 'Adam', 'Will']


def get_len(name):
    return len(name)


print(max(names, key=get_len))
print(min(names, key=get_len))
# or
print(max(names, key=lambda name : len(name)))
print(min(names, key=lambda name : len(name)))
```

How do I know whether it is possible or not possible to use a function as a 'key=func' argument?

Comment: If it accepts an item from the list as its argument and returns a value that is comparable (such as an int). By the way, instead of defining `get_len` you could just use `key=len`.

Comment: Although there's a more formal definition, here's my understanding of it: The number of arguments in the function should be equal to the number of parameters in the lambda expression

Comment: You can use any callable you want ! Of course you will get incorrect result by doing that. It should have accept one parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the documentation, `min()` (and `max()`) expect a one-argument ordering function like that used for `list.sort()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min

So, what's expected is a function that takes a single argument from the collection that `min()` or `max()` is applied to and that returns a single value that can be ordered with `<` and `>`.

So, for `names`, which is a list of strings, that would be a function that takes a single `str` as an argument and returns something that is comparable using `<` or `>` to order the strings, for example its length.

So, even this would work:

```
names = ['Rodrigo', 'Matthew', 'Adam', 'Will']

print(max(names, key=len))
```

To answer your general question "How do I know whether it is possible or not possible to use a function as a `key` argument to `min()`?"

You check if the function:

- accepts a single argument
- the type of the argument matches the type of the elements of the collection `min()` will be applied to
- returns a value that can be ordered using `<` and `>`

Answer (score 0):

`keyfunc` must return a value with a defined `__lt__` (less than) operation.  `max` applies the function to each element of `names`, and returns the element with the highest value, as defined by that less-than relationship.  If multiple elements of `names` test as not less than any other element, then `max` will return the first of these.

Perhaps a simpler way to look at it is that if the return type of your function is sortable (int, float, str, etc.), then the function is usable.

Your definition of `len(element)` works just fine -- as I expect you already tested.